# tax_query will produce nothing

Tags: tax-query

I want to display custom type posts from a custom taxonomy category so I did this:

```
$news = get_posts(
array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 82,
        ),
    )
); 
$postslist = get_posts( $news );    

foreach ($postslist as $crap) { ?>
     <a href="<?php $crap->title; ?>"><?php $crap->title; ?></a>
<?php }?>
```

I get nothing from this. Why is that? I double checked the category ID and its correct. Also, I used the Custom post types plugin to register the custom taxonomy.

Comment: This is the 3rd time you've asked this question in as many days.

Comment: because i havent received a good answer yet...

Comment: It is unfortunate that you haven't received an answer yet but you cannot recreate the same question multiple times in hope for better results. That's spammy behavior. If you want to get your question more attention try sharing it on Social Media or various other channels. After a couple days you may also put a bounty on your question which will bring extra attention to it.

Comment: @CainNuke  you shouldn't hardcode term IDs in PHP code. If it got deleted by accident the code would be broken and need changing to work again. It would also break on site migration, or moving between production/test/staging/etc. Instead use the `slug`. Then if it's deleted by accident you can create a new term with the same name and it'll work again. Also don't call the array `$crap`? And +1 to what Howdy said. If you don't get a good answer then you edit and update your question, you don't post a brand new question.

Comment: @CainNuke what's the slug/name of term 82? And why are you using `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query`?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I had to learn it the hard way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [WP_Query documentation on tax_queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) we can see it accepts a nested array as a parameter. Compare that to the provided code:

```php
'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => 82,
),
```

Should look like:

```php
'tax_query' => [
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => 82,
    ]
],
```

Comment: thank you but it still wont work.

Comment: It's likely not something with the given code then. Are you sure the post type is `news`, the taxonomy is `news_category` and the term ID is `82`? If so, how & where are you trying to display these posts? I.E. template file, function call, plugin?

Comment: in a template file called news.php. The term ID is the ID of the category, isnt it? When I click the edit button for that category the ULR is something like this: wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=news_category&tag_ID=82&post_type=news

Comment: Maybe try `'terms' => array( 82 )`. Are there posts assigned to that specific category?

Comment: No, no use. This thins is really driving me crazy...

Comment: @CainNuke Does your template call `get_header()` and `get_footer()`? Does your header file call `wp_head()` and footer file call `wp_footer()`?

Comment: I found out what the problem was. I must use WP_Query and not get_posts. Thank you.

Comment: [The `get_posts()` functions _uses_ WP_Query though.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)